# How to stop redirecting from http to https?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, cpanel

I recently buy a domain that is *teachingbrains.online* and connect it with the free hosting by **infinityfree**. In the free hosting control panel there is an option of Softaculous Apps Installer from where I install WordPress to my website.

**Main Problem:**

Inside the Wordpress Admin Dashboard at the general > setting of the website, there is an option of WordPress URL and Site URL which pre looks as

```
WordPress URL: http://teachingbrains.online/wp-admin/

Site URL:      http://teachingbrains.online/
```

But I changed both URLs to https

```
WordPress URL: https://teachingbrains.online/wp-admin/

Site URL:      https://teachingbrains.online/
```

Since I don't have any SSL linked with my website hence whenever I tried to open my website or WordPress Admin Dashboard it shows me ***This site can’t provide a secure connection***

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the database of your WordPress instance, you can have a look at the `wp_options` table through phpMyAdmin or something alike.

You will find two fields, I think they are called `siteurl` and `home`, and you should change those back to non-https.

Comment: I searched in my whole directory(Cpanel) but did not found any instance like wp_options or wp-options if you can please provide a path to reach that then it will be very thankful.

Comment: You need to check the database, not the "Cpanel".

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to stop redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS

1. Go to chrome://net-internals and select “HSTS” from the drop-down.
   Enter the domain name under the “Delete domain” and press the Delete
   button.
   Now clear your browser cache:

> `Settings > Show advanced settings… > Privacy > Clear browsing data`

2. You can use rewrite rules to redirect https requests to HTTP inside of the subdirectory. Create a .htaccess file inside the tools
   directory and add the following content:

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
> RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
> ```

Make sure that apache mod_rewrite is enabled.

3. If you have access to Control Panel, then open CPanel

> Domains > Redirects > Select the Domain Name > Alter Redirects >
> change to HTTP from HTTPS > Redirect It